# Karma not finding my jasmine test, TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When trying to run my jasmine test, which is testing my angular customer directive "book directive" using test-runner karma i'm getting the following output errors: (I'm getting various TypeErrors from each script file, not even finding my test let alone showing a failing test))

**Karma Output**

```
------ Discover test started ------
Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angular.module')
in file:///c:/users/ray/documents/visual%20studio%202013/projects/requirejsdemo/requirejsdemo/scripts/angular-route.js (line 24)
While Running:c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-route.js

Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'angular.$$minErr')
in file:///c:/users/ray/documents/visual%20studio%202013/projects/requirejsdemo/requirejsdemo/scripts/angular-sanitize.js (line 8)
While Running:c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-sanitize.js

Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define
at global code in file:///c:/users/ray/documents/visual%20studio%202013/projects/requirejsdemo/requirejsdemo/tests/newfeaturetests/directivetest.js (line 3)
While Running:c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\tests\newfeaturetests\directivetest.js

Error: TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
in file:///c:/users/ray/documents/visual%20studio%202013/projects/requirejsdemo/requirejsdemo/scripts/angular-mocks.js (line 17)
While Running:c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-mocks.js

[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-mocks.js
[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-route.js
[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-sanitize.js
[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular-scenario.js
[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\angular.js
[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\scripts\jasmine.js
[Karma] [Warning] [Discover] Could not get settings for c:\users\ray\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\requirejsdemo\requirejsdemo\tests\newfeaturetests\directivetest.js
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:17.4009953) ==========
```

**karma.conf file**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '../',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        "Scripts/angular.js",
           { pattern: "Scripts/require.js", included: false },
              { pattern: "Scripts/jasmine.js", included: false },
                 { pattern: "Scripts/angularAMD.js", included: false },
                    { pattern: "Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js", included: false },
        { pattern: "Js/**/*.js", included: false },
        { pattern: "tests/NewFeatureTests/*.js", included: false },
        { pattern: "Js/NewFeature/*.html", include: false },

        "tests/test-main.js"
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        "Js/main.js"
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        "Js/**.*.html": ["ng-html2js"]
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    plugins: [
        'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
    ],

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
})
}
```

**Jasmine Test**

```
'use strict'

define(['angular', 'jquery',], function (angular) {

    describe('bookDirective', function () {
      var el;

        // Load the myApp module, which contains the directive
        beforeEach(module('testModule'));
        beforeEach(module('Js/NewFeature/Book.html'));

        // Store references to $rootScope and $compile
        // so they are available to all tests in this describe block
        beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
            // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
            scope = _$rootScope_;

            scope.color = "red";
            scope.title = "ghost";
            //create and compile directive
            el = angular.element("<book title='Ghost' color='red'></book>");

            // compile the dom node and apply the scope, this will return a getter function
            $compile(el)(scope);

            scope.$digest(); // update the html
        }));

        it('background colour of book should be red', function () {
            // check if background color is red
            expect(el.css('background-color').toEqual('red'));
        });

    });

});
```

How do I get my tests to run?

Answer (score 0):

your base path is  **basePath: '../',**.  So, files array should be

```
files: [
        "../scripts/angular.js",
       "../scripts/angular-route.js",
       "../scripts/angular-mocks.js",
       "../scripts/angular-sanitize.js",
       "../scripts/angular-scenario.js",
       "../scripts/jasmine.js",
       "../tests/newfeaturetests/directivetest.js",
       "../tests/test-main.js"
    ]
```

Please check base path.

Please also check your **index.html** file for all script JS that you included and list it in **files** Array.Otherwise it will lead error if one of those script will dependency for other.

Also in your jasmine test **beforeEach(module('Js/NewFeature/Book.html'));**

this is wrong.This is not module name registered with angular app.Please check it.remove it.

Also please refer [directive testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) for more.